# Viewpager + Actionbarsherlock not compiling the android-support library

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-studio

I am trying to use the `viewPager + Actionbarsherlock` at the same time in my project. But everytime I build I get 74 errors. All complaining about things like

```
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

   //Other class 
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

after some searching I found out that the problem is with the `android-support library`.
I am using `android studio`. Can anybody tell me how I should build up my `project structure` in android studio ?

Thanks!

Comment: Judging by your reputation, I thought you'd rather post the details of the errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that [ActionBarSherlock is using an older version](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock/libs) (it's five months old) of the android-support-library. Replace the android-support-v4.jar i ActionBarSherlock/libs with the one you use in your main project.

Comment: Oké now I don't get the previous erros any more but a lot of new ones... It starts with this Android Dex: [genkOnStage] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Comment: Do you use any other libraries? Have you tried cleaning the project? Add/remove ABS? Post more exception details.

Comment: I solved it by removing the abs and added it again. Thanks for the help !